# Nginx empty Accept-Encoding leads to timeout

Tags: nginx, compression, reverse-proxy

When I want to replace a string in a Nginx reverse proxy I use

```
sub_filter 'https://upstream.com' 'http://www.localhost:8080';
sub_filter_once off;
```

But it doesn't work (because its gzipped) so I add

```
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
```

But then the request times out (gateway timeout). I wonder how this could be possible, I tried to do a GET to upstream.com with postman with `Accept-Encoding` header set to empty and it worked fine, so it is an issue on my side.

My config looks like:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://www.upstream.com;
            proxy_hide_header 'x-frame-options';
            proxy_cookie_domain ~^(.*)$ "http://www.localhost:8080";
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none";
            sub_filter 'https://www.upstream.com' 'http://www.localhost:8080';
            sub_filter_once off;
            sub_filter_types text/html;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        }
    }
}
```

PS: upstream.com is just an example, I use another URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [gunzip](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html) module. More info [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/).

```
http {
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://www.upstream.com;
            proxy_hide_header 'x-frame-options';
            proxy_cookie_domain ~^(.*)$ "http://www.localhost:8080";
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none";
            sub_filter 'https://www.upstream.com' 'http://www.localhost:8080';
            sub_filter_once off;
            sub_filter_types text/html;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "gzip";
            gunzip on;
        }
    }
}
```